# ICU conversion with ucnv_toUnicode

Tags: c, unicode, icu

I am new to ICU (IBM's unicode library).  I am reading a large file in chunks, and I am trying to convert it from UTF-8 to UTF-16.

I am using ucnv_toUnicode, and I am running into a problem: how do I determine how many bytes where written by the converter to the target?

```
        ucnv_toUnicode(conv, &target, targetLimit, 
                   &source, sourceLimit, NULL,
                   feof(f)?TRUE:FALSE,         
                   &status);
```

target is a 4096 byte buffer.

According to the api docs, it will be moved by ucnv_toUnicode to point after the last UChar copied.  It seems like I should be able to do some sort of arithmatic between target and the original position to determine this, but I'm new to C.  Can anyone give me a hand?

Now suppose that I want to fwrite() what was put into target.  what would I pass to fwrite for the size and number of units?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation says:

> Target [...] starts out pointer at the first available UChar in the output buffer, and ends up pointing after the last UChar written to the output.

So it's simple:

```
char input[SLEN];
UChar output[TLEN];

char const * source = input;
UChar * target = output;

ucnv_toUnicode(conv, &target, output + TLEN,
               &source, input + SLEN, NULL, feof(f), &status);
```

Now you have written `target - output` UChars to the output buffer.

The same goes for the input; you'll have consumed `source - input` chars (= bytes).